# Is it possible to add a sprite to a joint?

Tags: unity

I want to have a joint between two objects, but I also want to highlight to the user that these two objects are connected together.

I am assuming this isn't the correct method, as a joint is just a component.

Note: I am a total Unity newbie.

I just want some method to indicate to a user which items are jointed together.

A code solution is totally fine - I am very comfortable programming. Maybe extending the joint class and adding a sprite selector?

Answer (score 1):

This link seems to indicate that the proper way to do this is via a script that links two objects with a line.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1766-physics-joints-in-unity-2d

EDIT:

The code for the line script is here (writing it to preserve it in case anyone needs it):

```
public class Line : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject gameObject1;          // Reference to the first GameObject
    public GameObject gameObject2;          // Reference to the second GameObject

    private LineRenderer line;                           // Line Renderer

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Add a Line Renderer to the GameObject
        line = this.gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        // Set the width of the Line Renderer
        line.SetWidth(0.05F, 0.05F);
        // Set the number of vertex fo the Line Renderer
        line.SetVertexCount(2);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // Check if the GameObjects are not null
        if (gameObject1 != null && gameObject2 != null)
        {
            // Update position of the two vertex of the Line Renderer
            line.SetPosition(0, gameObject1.transform.position);
            line.SetPosition(1, gameObject2.transform.position);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just set the two game objects of the script, either programmatically or in the IDE. After that, a line render component will generate, and all you have to do here is set a material for the line render component.

This very nicely and neatly rendered a line between my two objects.

Comment: If this has solved your problem, it would be best to describe briefly the steps you took to solve it, so that future readers can benefit from your answer. A link is a nice resource but they can be broken in the future. If this hasn't solved your problem, but you think it would, it would be better to try it out and update your question/answer.

Comment: It has solved my problem. I'll edit my answer and add more detail as soon as I understand the script in detail.

Answer (score -3):

You can add sprite via material. It is good and with great control.

Comment: But can it be added to multiple joints? I don’t think so

Comment: Material can be added to multiple joints. Adjust tiling in x, y axis.

Comment: This answer would be better if it described or showed the steps to do this.